# For which integer values of $n$ does there exist an integer $m$ such that $n^{3} - m^{2} = -23$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, quadratic-residues

> For which integer values of $n$ does there exist an integer $m$ such that $n^{3} - m^{2} = -23$?

I'm having a lot of trouble with this one, any help would be appreciated :)

So far, I've seen that if the expression were a perfect square we would have:
$n^{3} + 23 = x^{2}$
For some integer $x$. From this I've deduced that $n^{3}$ must be congruent to $x^{2}$ modulo $23$, however, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $n^3+23=m^2$ for some integers $n,m$.  Observe that
$$(n+3)(n^2-3n+9)=n^3+27=m^2+4.$$

If $m$ is odd, then $n$ is even.  Since $m^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, we must get $n^3\equiv 1-23\equiv 2\pmod{8}$.  However, this is impossible as $n^3\equiv 0\pmod{8}$ for every even integer $n$.  Thus $m$ is even.

Since $m$ is even, say $m=2k$, we get that $n$ is odd.  Because $m^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, we obtain $n^3\equiv -23\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  Thus $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  That is,
$$k^2+1=\frac{m^2+4}{4}=\frac{n+3}{4}\left(n^2-3n+9\right).$$
Since $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, we must have
$$n^2-3n+9\equiv 1-3+9\equiv 3\pmod{4}.$$
Because $n^2-3n+9>0$, we conclude that a prime natural number $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ must divide $n^2-3n+9$.  Thus, $k^2+1$ is divisible by $p$, so that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, which implies that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific case of Mordell curve ( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MordellCurve.html ) with $k =23.$ It has no solution which you can see here https://oeis.org/A054504.

For proof, refer https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math5230f12/handouts/mordelleqn1.pdf and try to prove it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Try to prove that every perfect square is congruent to $0$ or $1(mod 4$).

Comment: Thanks for your response :). This is quite easy to do, but I'm afraid I don't see the connection. Could you offer a follow up hint?

Comment: Using the hint, it can be shown that $n^3$=$2 (mod4) $ or $n^3$=$1 (mod4) $ . Isn't this much easier to deal with now?

Comment: Note that actually $n^3 \equiv 0 \mod 4$  ,  $n^3 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ or $ n^3 \equiv 3 \mod 4 .$

Comment: Yeah, so the idea is to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: I am afraid it's still not clear what you are trying to prove.